# Hide Excluded fields not selected in dropdown selected (qlikview)

Tags: qlikview

Please how can we Hide Excluded in the Dropdown Select list in qlikview

Thank you

Comment: Whats the point in that? anyways ,for this use case just use straight table with this one dimension...you can format it to look like list box and it will show only selected value by default...

Comment: The purpose is in a chart table the user can see just dimensions that he had to be filtred

Comment: That is exactly what he will see....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a calculated dimension `=aggr(Dim1, Dim1)` instead of having Dim1 as dimension in the table.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you !